# How do we combine multiple row values into single delimited row using Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

How do we combine multiple row values into single row using Apache Drill?

**Example** :

Input:

```
a
b
c
```

Output:

```
a,b,c
```

In oracle or any other database we have `listagg` function  to achieve this. How do we achieve this using Apache Drill?

Answer (score 1):

- Drill hasn't `listagg` function, since it is not a standard SQL ANSI
  function. But you can create your own UDF for this purpose [1].
- Also you can contribute to Drill to create this function or similar PIVOT
  function.
- A case statement along with aggregation might do the trick
  [2].
- Also consider the similar approach like in Hive [3]

[1] https://drill.apache.org/docs/adding-custom-functions-to-drill-introduction/

[2] http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/drill-user/201606.mbox/%3CCAAOiHjHyCajBDVerE9fFbgHUyQ+3wYAcX84ZaoUVbAyj0LpjBw@mail.gmail.com%3E

[3] http://hadoopmania.blogspot.com/2015/12/transposepivot-table-in-hive.html