# Query to get comma seperated values in column using group by

Tags: apache-drill

I'm using to create a query to get comma separated values in column using group by in Apache Drill.

Data

```
ID    SomeOtherId   Name
1     1             AAA
2     1             BBB
3     1             CCC
4     2             DDD
5     2             EEE
```

Expected Output

```
SomeOtherId     Name
1               AAA, BBB, CCC
2               DDD, EEE
```

Any help on how to do this using Apache Drill please ?

Comment: I think your data is wrong, the last line should be `5 2 EEE`, right?

Also, your output is not comma-separated, but comma-and-space-separated, is that what you need?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of this other question, but both need the LISTAGG (oracle) or GROUP_CONCAT (MySQL) functionality of other databases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326070